Who should sign the transaction when new account is initialized?
Why is the counter account key signing the transaction and not the user wallet?
  await program.methods.initialize()
  .accounts({
    counter: counter.publicKey,
    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
  }).signers([counter]).rpc();

  console.log('Counter initialized with public key:', counter.publicKey.toString());


When you create a new account on Solana, the account needs to be signed by the keypair that is going to "own" or initialize that account. In this case, counter is a newly created account that you are initializing.
The signers([counter]) array indicates that the transaction is being signed by the keypair associated with the counter account. This is necessary because this account does not exist yet on the blockchain and needs to be created.
Imagine counter is like an empty vault that you’re placing on the blockchain. To put it there, the vault’s “owner” (i.e., the counter keypair) needs to sign off on it. The user might be the person who will use the vault, but they don't need to sign off on creating it—only on actions that would affect it later.
The counter keypair must sign the transaction because it is authorizing the creation of the new account (in this case, the counter account).
The user wallet is involved as an account in the transaction, but its signature isn’t necessary for this specific operation.

TL;DR, anyone can sign the transaction to create a new account as long as they have enough lamports.
Using anchor, when creating a new account, especially PDAs you are required to specify the payer of the transaction who's mostly the signer
#[account(mut)]
user: Signer<'info>,

#[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 32 + 32 + 8 + 1024 + 8)]
pub pda: Account<'info, PDA>,

If you are creating an on-curve address using the system program, you will need to sign the transaction which I might assume is happening in the above example,
Using TS
const signer = ... // your signer KP

const counter = Keypair.generate();

let createAccIx = await SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: signer.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: counter.publicKey,
    lamports: rentExemptionAmount,
    space: 8 + 32,
    programId: SystemProgram.programId,
});

const tx = new Transaction().add(createAccIx);

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [
   signer,
   counter,
]);

ref: https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/accounts/create-account
